# Temperature sensor on a long wire (100ft)

Tags: sensor, temperature, thermocouple, thermometer

I'd like to monitor the temperature of a variety of locations around my house but I don't want to rely on wireless technology. Are there temperature sensors that can be connected over long distances (100-200ft) using regular wires? I'd like to connect these sensors into a into a temperature data logger so I can see trends.

Do I want a thermocouple? USB connection? Ethernet? The average fridge/freezer thermometer technology seems fine for my usage but I want more distance.

Comment: I have some Bluetooth sensors scattered about that work pretty well.

Comment: Check zigbee standard. A lot of ready to use devices. That standard created for making network of battery operated devices.

Comment: Which data logger do you plan to use (what types of sensors can it accept)?
How are the sensors located, I mean, does each of them have it's own wire? Or are they positioned along a line or so? 
You probably do not want to use thermocouples, please.
Pt100 and Pt1000 in 3- or 4-wire connection can be quite long....

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a digital sensor such as the [DS18B20](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/DS18B20.pdf) "one wire" sensor, since you'd like to monitor multiple locations. "One wire" means that, in addition to positive/negative power, only one signal wire is needed... or the device can even be used in a "parasitic power" circuit, so only a twisted pair is sufficient.

**Multiple** temp sensors can be connected in parallel, along the same line, because *each is identified by a unique 64-bit code*. This makes wiring the house for temp measurement much easier -- just run one long cable, attaching sensors at any place along it, even adding more sensors later.

You can use an [Arduino microcontroller](https://lastminuteengineers.com/ds18b20-arduino-tutorial/), a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-ds18b20-temperature-sensor-tutorial/), or some other device to interface with the sensors. Here's how a Pi [queries from each sensor, by its ID](https://raspberryautomation.com/connect-multiple-ds18b20-temperature-sensors-to-a-raspberry-pi/). Data could be logged by the micro-PC or sent to another device, or even sent over the internet. There's a tutorial at
[blog@cavelab](https://blog.cavelab.dev/2019/10/rpi-ds18b20-temp-sensors/), too.